# rebin an array in python to have at least N counts in each entry

Tags: python, arrays, bin, group

I have an array as:

```
A = [1,8,2,6,4,8,1,0,1,6,7,3,1,4,9,1,2,1,2,1,1,2]
```

and I'd like to rebin/group it into a smaller size array, which has at least a value of `10` in each entry, i.e.:

```
A_reb = [[1,8,2],[6,4],[8,1,0,1],[6,7],[3,1,4,9],[1,2,1,2,1,1,2]]
A_reb = [11, 10, 10, 13, 17, 10]
```

Is there an effective way to do it in python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if there's a general solution. After all, your source list (for it is a list and *not* an array) may have values that make your objective impossible - e.g., [2,2,3]

Comment: The question seems to use Stackoverflow as chatGPT. You can show your implementation and then we can discuss how to improve it to be more efficient.

Comment: What should happen if the final `2` is removed? (As this would make the final bin equal to 8)

Comment: @MatBailie Remove the last 2 and the sum of the final bin would be 8 - wouldn't it?

Comment: @ctrlz edited, but it doesn't change the point of the question

Comment: @CtrlZ to answer your (now deleted) question, this differs in the way to compute the sum. It adds one element at each iteration instead of restarting the sum (e.g., 1, 1+2, 1+2+1, 1+2+1+2, 1+2+1+2+1, 1+2+1+2+1+1, 1+2+1+2+1+1+2 for the last group in your case). It's otherwise quite similar (which is why I only commented to your answer, until you requested me to provide an answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the items, add the value to current total. If the total passes the threshold, `append` to the output and reset the total. Optionally add the last (incomplete) group to the output:

```
A = [1,8,2,6,4,8,1,0,1,6,7,3,1,4,9,1,2,1,2,1,1,2]

threshold = 10

start = 0
total = 0
out = []
for end, val in enumerate(A, start=1):
    total += val
    if total >= threshold:
        out.append(A[start:end])
        total = 0
        start = end

# if you want to add the last incomplete group (if any)
if start < len(A):
    out.append(A[start:])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 8, 2], [6, 4], [8, 1, 0, 1], [6, 7], [3, 1, 4, 9], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def rebin_array(arr):
    rebinned = []
    current_group = []
    current_sum = 0
    
    for num in arr:
        if current_sum + num <= 10:
            current_group.append(num)
            current_sum += num
        else:
            rebinned.append(current_group)
            current_group = [num]
            current_sum = num
    
    if current_group:
        rebinned.append(current_group)
    
    return rebinned

A = [1,8,2,6,4,8,1,0,1,6,7,3,1,4,9,1,2,1,2,1,1,2]
A_rebinned = rebin_array(A)
A_rebinned_sum = [sum(group) for group in A_rebinned]

print("A_rebinned:", A_rebinned)
print("A_rebinned_sum:", A_rebinned_sum)
```